# Logstash throws unexpected error: <ArgumentError: Setting "" hasn't been registered>,

Tags: logstash, jmx

I followed instruction: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jmx.html

to setup cassandra jmx metric monitoring.

My logstash.yml is as follows:

```
input {
    jmx {
        path => "/home/foo/elastic/logstash"
        polling_frequency => 15
        type => "jmx"
        nb_thread => 4
    }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Under `/home/foo/elastic/logstash`, I define a `jmx.conf` file with following info:

```
//Required, JMX listening host/ip
"host" : "192.168.1.139",
//Required, JMX listening port
"port" : 7199,
//Optional, the username to connect to JMX
"username" : "foo",
//Optional, the password to connect to JMX
"password": "foo",
//Optional, use this alias as a prefix in the metric name. If not set use <host>_<port>
"alias" : "cassandra",
```

Then I run logstash in the command:

```
sudo bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/logstash.yml --path.settings /etc/logstash --debug
```

I get the following error:

> Sending Logstash's logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
>
> [FATAL] 2017-10-28 22:57:23.812 [main] runner - An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#, :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:32:in `get_setting'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:64:in`set_value'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:83:in `merge'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in`each'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:83:in `merge'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:135:in`validate_all'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:243:in `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:67:in`run'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:204:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:132:in`run'", "/usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:71:in `(root)'"]}

Answer (score 3):

I figure it out myself.

There are 2 types of settings for Logstash, one is for Logstash, one for pipeline. Typically the one in /etc/logstash is for Logstash, and pipeline one is in /etc/logstash/conf.d. I used pipeline one for Logstash, which creates all errors.

Answer (score 1):

**The Problem**

The error message is not pretty clear but the `logstash.yml` file should contains data in **YAML** format. And here it doesn't (Your data `input { jmx { path => ...` is clearly  not on **YAML** format.

**Why does it matter ?**

Because Logstash has two types of configuration files:

- **pipeline configuration files** with the `.conf` extension which define the Logstash processing pipeline and
- **settings files**, which specify options that control Logstash startup and execution. ( `logstash.yml`, `pipelines.yml`, `jvm.options`, etc...). This means :

1. If You want to configure data input, filter or output, you should put your configuration in a `logstash.conf` file (or in a file having a `.conf` extension)
2. If you want to configure logstash and you do not want to pass options or flags at the command line level, you can set them here in `logstash.yml`.

**How to fix it ?**

0. You can ignore (or delete) the file `/etc/logstash/logstash.yml` if you do not have any option to pass to set logstash startup behaviour.
1. Set the content of the file `/etc/logstash/pipelines.yml` to the following

```yaml
# This file is where you define your pipelines. You can define multiple.
# For more information on multiple pipelines, see the documentation:
#   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/multiple-pipelines.html

- pipeline.id: main
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/*.conf"
```

2. Put your logstash data configuration pipeline in the file  `/etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf` as following

```json
input {
    jmx {
        path => "/home/foo/elastic/logstash"
        polling_frequency => 15
        type => "jmx"
        nb_thread => 4
    }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

**Et voilà :=)**

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you did mistake in config file - it should be the JSON object, but I don't see the opening `{` at beginning of config - see example of config file in article that you refer.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. In the real file jmx.conf, I do have {} as json object, I copied only the changes I made to the jmx definition.

Answer (score 0):

I tried following steps and it worked for me:

1. The input and output section specified by you under logstash.yml file should be in conf file e.g. jmx.conf
2. Comment everything under logstash.yml so that default settings are loaded by logstash.

It resolved the issue.